# how to copy a dictionary in another java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have 2 dictionaries and I want to make a copy from the first one in the second and then the ways of each other to be different.Here is the adt of my dictionaries implemented:

```
public class CollectionDic1<K,Integer>  implements Id<K,Integer> , Serializable{
private K key;
private Integer value;
private Map<K,Integer> dict;

public CollectionDic1(){
    dict = new HashMap<K,Integer>();
}

public void put(K key, Integer value){
    dict.put(key, value);
}
public int getSize(){
    return dict.size();
}
public K getKey(){ return key; }
public Integer getValue(){return value;}
public void remove(K key){
    try{
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new ExceptionRepo();
        else
            dict.remove(key);

    }catch (ExceptionRepo ex){
            System.err.println("Error: Dictionary is empty.");

    }

}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return dict.isEmpty();      
}

public Integer get(K k){
    return dict.get(k);
}

public boolean containsKey(K k){
    return dict.containsKey(k);     
}

public void update (K k, Integer v){
    dict.put(k, v);
}
public String toString(){
    Set<K> all = dict.keySet();
    Object[] keysA = all.toArray();
    String res = "";
    for (int i=0; i<dict.size();i++){
        Integer v = dict.get(keysA[i]);
        res += keysA[i].toString() + " : " + v.toString() + "\r\n";         
    }
    return res;

}

}
```

And here I tried to do:

```
public void execute{
      //prg is unimportant
      Id<Object,Integer> first= prg.getDict();
      Id<Object,Integer> second = new CollectionDic1<Object,Integer>();
      for (int i=0; i<first.getSize(); i++){
          second.put(first.getKey(), first.getValue());
      }
```

In for I want to add the keys and the values already existing in the first dictionary but I don't know how.Any ideas?

Comment: By `dictionary` you mean `HashMap`? Java doesn't have `dictionaries`...

Comment: Yes, HashMaps.I'm sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Map.Entry` functiomality

```
for (Map.Entry<String, JButton> entry : first.entrySet())
{
    second.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

`Map.Entry` will give you pairs of key and value.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the `Maps` entryset in your `CollectionDic1` class.

```
public Set getEntrySet(){
    return dict.entrySet();
}
```

Then, in the `execute` method iterate over each key in that set:

```
Iterator it = first.getEntrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    second.put(pair.getKey(),pair.getValue());
}
```